# Azure AD token service does't response refresh_token and id_token

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to work with Outlook REST API. I have to authenticate by Azure AD and I have one little problem with that. When I exchange `authorization code` to `access token` response of https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token does not contains refresh_token and id_token which I need. My code sending request is

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
req.UserAgent = "Example/1.0";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string data = "";
    data += "grant_type=authorization_code";
    data += "&code=" + Request.QueryString("code");
    data += "&scope=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Join(" ", scopes));
    data += "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectUri);
    data += "&client_id=" + appId;
    data += "&client_secret=" + appPassword;
    sw.Write(data);
}
HttpWebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
    Response.End();
}
```

Example of response from this code

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.Read https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Read",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 0,
    "access_token": "EwAYA+l3B/Qk ... IpfA0C"
}
```

I don't know what I am doing different than https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net because there response contains all properties.

Comment: For the refresh token you have to ask for Offline_Access scope while requesting the authorization code and for the id_token, I guess you need Profile scope. The id_token is basically for app specific use, just to verify that the token is getting used by specific app only and no other app is using the token on behalf of the other app. 
So try yo request the offline_access scope that might give you the refresh token.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you post is as answer? I will mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the refresh token you have to ask for `Offline_Access` scope while requesting the authorization code and for the id_token, I guess you need `Profile` scope. The id_token is basically for app specific use, just to verify that the token is getting used by specific app only and no other app is using the token on behalf of the other app. So try yo request the `offline_access` scope that might give you the refresh token.